# How will i re-train my supervised learning model from outputs of the previous inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, data-science, recurrent-neural-network

Let's suppose I have a pre-trained supervised model for fault detection in an electric motor.

Which takes inputs as frequency, amplitude, etc and output as bearing fault, misalignment fault, or other faults.

```
    Inputs                          output

S.no  freq       amplitude         
1     9282         753      | -->     misalignment fault      
2     7287.98      627      |
```

suppose there are some sensors on my electric motors, which sends data to the pre-trained model and it outputs as misalignment fault.

if I want to use this prediction to re-train my model how will I do so? 
how do I know the predicted outcome is valid? or it will not affect the performance of my model?

I am New to machine learning and neural network, help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions and not about design recommendations; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a pre-trained model, your outcomes are predicted by the pre-trained model. If you feed these outcomes back to the pre-trained model and retrain it. It won't help you to improve performances. You will need to validate the outcomes. You can perform 3 actions here. Remain the correct prediction, remove the incorrect prediction, fix the incorrect prediction. You can do any of the three or do all of them. It depends on the workload you can handle.